# Django помогите разобраться в параметре related_name

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model

Никак не пойму в книги что имеют в виду

> related_name — имя атрибута записи первичной модели, предназначенного для
> доступа к связанным записям вторичной модели, в виде строки:

```
class Bb(models.Model) :
rubric = models.ForeignKey(Rubric, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
related_name='entries')
first_rubric = Rubric.objects.first()
bbs = first_rubric.entries.all()
```

> Если доступ из записи первичной модели к связанным записям вторичной
> модели не требуется, можно указать Django не создавать такой атрибут и
> тем самым немного сэкономить системные ресурсы. Для этого достаточно
> присвоить параметру related паше СИМВОЛ "ПЛЮС". Если параметр не
> указан, то атрибут такого рода получит стандартное имя вида <имя
> связанной вторичной модели>_set

Из всего что я понял, `related_name` это имя которое даётся для строки первичной записи модели, но непонятно зачем . Пишут для предназначенного для
доступа к связанным записям вторичной модели, в виде строки

Вот тут нифига не понятно. К каким связанным записям если во вторичной модели просто взяли и объявили поле rubric у которого стоит этот атрибут ( entires)? Что значит связанная запись тут , когда стоит поле с внешним ключом просто и нету никакого признака entires там метка или нет? Как он вытаскивать будет записи с меткой entires?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44161722/9653855